# Suppressing ICMP protocol 47 unreachable with userspace GRE implementation

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, tunneling, gre

For reasons that would require a lot of irrelevant context to explain, I'm handling GRE packets with a userspace process with a `SOCK_RAW`/`IPPROTO_GRE` socket. This is working fine, except that despite having a raw socket accepting the GRE packets, the kernel is generating ICMP protocol unreachable responses for each GRE packet it receives. Short of blocking these with a firewall rule, is there a way to prevent them? Some way to tell the system the packets received on the raw socket were accepted?

Comment: Have you spoken to the developer of that userspace process?

Comment: Pehaps [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/711204/83024) and its answer may help. Do you have a GRE kernel module loaded?